# How to run through XML and print only those elements that have a specific attribute in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transform, xslt-2.0

```
I need to iterate through the XML and print only those elements that have a specific attribute. For example - 

<root>
<fruits>
<name>apple</name>
<size ps:oldvalue="big">small</size>
<fruits>
<veggies>
<name>cabbage</name>
<size>small</size>
<price ps:oldvalue="30.0">40.0</price>
</veggies>
</root>
```

So, I need to pick up all the elements that have the oldvalue attribute and the output should have the name and the element that has the oldvalue attribute:

```
<root>
<name>apple<name>
<size ps:oldvalue="big">small</size>
<name>cabbage</name>
<price ps:oldvalue="30.0">40.0</price>
</root>
```

I have looked at using the identity template, but have been unsuccessful:

```
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*[(name()='@ps:oldvalue')]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not well-formed, when I correct it to

```
<root xmlns:ps="http://example.com/ps">
<fruits>
<name>apple</name>
<size ps:oldvalue="big">small</size>
</fruits>
<veggies>
<name>cabbage</name>
<size>small</size>
<price ps:oldvalue="30.0">40.0</price>
</veggies>
</root>
```

and apply

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:ps="http://example.com/ps">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*/@ps:oldvalue]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name | *[@ps:oldvalue]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I get

```
<root xmlns:ps="http://example.com/ps">
<name>apple</name><size ps:oldvalue="big">small</size>
<name>cabbage</name><price ps:oldvalue="30.0">40.0</price>
</root>
```